# Function doesn't work in IE but works well in FF and chrome. What is my mistake?

Tags: javascript, function, internet-explorer

The code here after works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, even outdated versions.
But in Internet Explorer, it doesn't with IE 7 or 8.
Not tested with IE 6 but shouldn't work (and it's not a problem)
Not tested with IE 9 (don't have it).

The error I got is : "**there's a bug because local_load is null or undefined**."

i have this call in my php page :

```
    <html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
    [... some html...]
    <?php
    include 'footer.php';
    ?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            local_load();
            initialize();
            return true;
        });
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

local_load() is in an external js file which is loaded through footer.php.
Local_load() 's content is this :

```
function local_load() {
    if ($.jStorage.storageAvailable() == true) {
        // we need to execute regulary this function.
        // It will stop automatically once the whole job is done.
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            display_something(true)
         }, 700, true);
    }
    else {
        Nostorage();
    }
    return true;
}
```

=================
Answering your questions :

Copied from the browser's source :

fonctions-map.js content :

```
function local_load() {

if ($.jStorage.storageAvailable() == true) {
    poi_recept = $.jStorage.get("poi_ids");
    if (poi_recept.length > 0) {
        poi_recept_compte = -1;
        poi_recept_interval = setInterval(function() {
            display_autourde(true)
        }, 700, true);
    }
}
else {
    Nostorage();
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're getting a syntax error when loading `footer.php`, which prevents the function from being defined.

Comment: **there's a bug because** doesn't sound like a real error message from IE. What is the exact error message?

Comment: You need to show more about how `local_load()` is actually loaded.  If it's in a dynamically loaded script file, then you will have a timing vulnerability that will vary with caching/browser/network situation.

Comment: The real error messaage is :
SCRIPT5007: La valeur de la propriété "local_load" est null ou non définie, pas un objet function

Comment: Maybe you can show us only a clean HTML generated by server. More languages you include in your questions, more time you will wait for an answer.

Comment: I'd suggest you do a View/Source in the browser and include the relevant portion of that.  We need to see what the browser sees, not what your PHP server sees.

Comment: I'm going to paste the source in the post above. But i can't take it from IE, i'll take it from FF ?

Comment: @Barmar : the console doesn't show errors before the one i encounter

Comment: @jfriend00 : local_load is in $(document).ready() => evrything should be loaded, no ?

Comment: @IvanKuckir i added the html generated. the whole file is about 900 lines, i took the interresting parts to show that evrything is loaded.

Comment: Can you put it online and send us a link?

Comment: @IvanKuckir sure i can. unfortunatelly you'll have to register. Use the invite code TESTIRL http://www.photoplace.me/ . Once loged, you're directed to the page with a problem. it's url is http://www.photoplace.me/rando_detail.php . You can't access it if you're not logged.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your comments that `local_load()` is defined inside a `document.ready()` callback in `fonctions-map.js`.  If that's the case, then it cannot be called from elsewhere because it's a local function that can only be called from within the scope in which it's defined.

So, if `fonctions-map.js` has it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function local_load() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Then, you can't call `local_load()` from elsewhere as it is not a public function.  You can make it a public function by moving its definition to the top level outside of any other function.

```
// define local_load() to be available to external callers
function local_load() {
    ...
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // only put code here that actually 
    // needs to wait until the document is ready to run
});
```

Comment: the $(document).ready(function() {} is in my html page. The function local_load() is in fonction-map.js. the $(document).ready(function() {} does not define local_load(). It just contains a call to local_load().

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't appear that you are including the file that contains local_load() in your html
Also You should have var when declaring interval
Other browsers are smart enough to figure this out but IE is not as smart.

eg

`var interval = setInterval( ....`

Comment: The question says that the file is being loaded in the HTML. IE is quite happy to assign values to globals.

Comment: It says local_load is in an external js file. So I'm guessing this file is not loaded.

Comment: @Mariatta the file is loaded (i added browser's source above). Also, the poi_recept_interval variable is declared with "var" at the top of the js file, to make it public as i need to refer to it almost anywhere.